# Embedded .swf animation not stopping on stop() call?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a .swf animation that I created in Flash Professional. To use it in my actionscript project, I embed it as follows:

```
[Embed(source="../lib/fetching.swf")]
public var Fetching:Class;
```

I then create an instance and add it to the stage as follows:

```
//class variable
var mc:MovieClip;

mc = new Fetching();
this.addChild(mc);
```

This causes my animation to appear on the screen and loop indefinitely. However, when calling `mc.stop()`, the animation does not stop. I've tried removing the movieclip from the stage by calling `removeChild(mc)` but adding a listener on the ENTER_FRAME event told me the movieclip is still playing over and over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set a Embed source mimeType, and you convert to ByteArray. and loaded. because you can't Direct Type Casting Fetching Class to MovieClip. If you define explicitly mimeType and convert by force, you'll get about `TypeError #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert YourProject_Fetching@108b780d1 to flash.display.MovieClip`

refer a following code.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class TestProject extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="../lib/fetching.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        public var Fetching:Class;

        public var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        private var mc:MovieClip;

        public function TestProject()
        {
            loader.loadBytes( new Fetching() as ByteArray );
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onSwfLoaded);
            this.addChild(loader);
        }

        private function onSwfLoaded(e:Event):void 
        {
            mc = loader.content as MovieClip;
            mc.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: swf files extend movieClip, so why shouldn't you be able to cast one as such?

Comment: I've always swf file not using a embed. only using a Loader. so i don't know exactly reason. but i knowing refer a this article: (1): [embedded-movieclip-gotcha](http://www.airtightinteractive.com/2008/05/as3-embedded-movieclip-gotcha/) (2): [embed movieclip from external swf runtime error](http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/as3-fix-embed-movieclip-from-external-swf-runtime-error/) (3): [problems-with-embedding-swfs-in-actionscript-or-flex](http://chrismweb.com/2011/03/20/problems-with-embedding-swfs-in-actionscript-or-flex/)

Comment: When you embed an SWF, what you get is something that extends Loader, not MovieClip. This Loader will call LoadBytes() with an embedded ByteArray containing the SWF. The embedded object will be a MovieClip only if you embed a specific symbol in the SWF.

Comment: Calling stop() on a Loader, of course, will not stop the movie that it  has loaded.

Comment: @wvxvw I was off slightly. What you get when you embed the whole SWF is a subclass of MovieClipLoaderAsset, a clip that contains a Loader, which loads the movie from an embedded ByteArray. The point is more or less the same though.

Comment: @wvxvw Well, I was using FB 4.0. According to the Adobe reference, MovieClipLoaderAsset is a part of Flex 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to be sure the embedded clip is compiled for the AVM2 (ie. that it targets AS3 and not AS1 or AS2)? An Avm1 swf may cast to a MovieClip without throwing an error, but will not then respond to commands.